# "non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context" and I only have 1 class

Tags: static, non-static

```
public class FileReaderProgram
{
  String stringComponent;
  int integerComponent;
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the absolute path of the file");
String fileName = in.next();             //Gets the file from the user
File inFile = new File(fileName);

Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(inFile);     //Constructs Scanner for reading the file

while (fileReader.hasNextLine())
{
  String line = fileReader.nextLine();                  //Gets line from the file
  Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);    //Constructs new scanner to analize the line
  String stringComponent = lineScanner.next();   //Obtains the first word of the data line
  while (!lineScanner.hasNextInt())        // Checks if there is another word in the string portion of the line
  {
    stringComponent = stringComponent + " " + lineScanner.next();
  }
  int integerComponent = lineScanner.nextInt();     //Obtains the integer part of the data line
  lineScanner.nextLine();   //Consume the newline
}

System.out.println(stringComponent);
System.out.println("integerComponent);


  }

}
```

My simple little code that's supposed to read multiple lines of a file (each line containing a string and an integer separated by a comma) and then read them back to me so I know its working. But I get the error message in the title for both variables and it highlights where I have them in System.out. Im utterly confused why, help please?

Comment: Remove the first two statements(member variables) that are in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Because main method is static, it cannot access any of the non-static variables defined in FileReaderProgram.  These variables are class-member variables and require an instance of FileReaderProgram to hold them.  You would need to either change them to static:

```
static String stringComponent;
int integerComponent;
```

or create a FileReaderProgram instance and access them through that.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    FileReaderProgram  frp = new FileReaderProgram();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Since you are redefining variables with the same names in the while loop, these are hiding the ones defined in the class, but the following 2 lines:

```
System.out.println(stringComponent);
System.out.println(integerComponent);
```

since they are outside the loop, are trying to access the member variables, which is invalid, like I said above.

Comment: You also have an extraneous double quote in last System.out.println (`System.out.println("integerComponent);
`)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that typo, any reason why it's now saying that "variable integerComponent might not have been initialized"

Comment: not sure, based on the current version of your code.  Class member variables are supposed to be initialized to 0, false, or null, depending on the type.  How did you resolve the non-static variable reference?  Could you post the latest version?

Comment: I set the initial integer to 0 and the initial string to " ", i really hope this doesn't effect how my code reads the file, unfortunately I wont find out till I fix this No such element error!

Answer (score 0):

Is this your completed code? You need to import scanner for one thing. You need to import io as well. Also, the last line, you didn't close off the string.

You will also need a try catch unless you throw the FileNotFoundException.

The issue here is that you do have a class, however, you only have a static method, which is main. Since main is static, you can't instantiate variables outside of main the way you did. You did it as if you have an object.

Two solutions: Move those two declarations into main and your good to go. Other solution is to add the keyword static before each variable. I would suggest you move stringComponent and intComponent inside main to prevent unwanted access. Limit their scope. The reason why it freaks out on the stringComponent is because that's an object. And if I remember correctly, there are no static references in the String API.

Comment: I added in that exception, and I cleared up my issue by moving the declarations inside main, but now it's giving me two errors saying that "they might have not been initialized" Well duh JAVA you're supposed to read them from the file that's why! why is it saying this?

Comment: Do this: String stringComponent = ""; and int intComponent = 0;

Comment: It is good code practice, in most cases, to always instantiate a variable with data, even if it is zero, or an empty string in the above examples. If you instantiate variables in C with no values, it can cause mayhem, dogs and cats living together, the end of the world kind of stuff.